# Search server with UDP

Tags: c#, search, server, udp

The task of the code is to find the servers that answers the #SERVER question. If I enter the server's IP address works fine, but not at 192.168.1.255 adress.

Thanks for the help!

My code is here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IPAddress.IPv6Any);

            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

            try
            {

                udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
                udpClient.Connect("192.168.1.255",80);


                // Sends a message to the host to which you have connected.
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("#SERVER");

                udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

                //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                // Uses the IPEndPoint object to determine which of these two hosts responded.
                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                             returnData.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                            " on their port number " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());

                udpClient.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
'''
```

Comment: IP address ending in 255 is not the Server IP address. It is a broadcast address for the subnet that is handled by a server in the gateway machine.  You can't connect to the address.  What protocol are you trying to implement?

Comment: Can you write my some example code what send UDP socket and wait for reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`192.168.1.255`or better ANY IP address ending with 255 is a broadcast address.
Messages sent to this IP are not targeted specifically but will (in the most cases) be broadcasted to all devices in your network (exceptions might be up to your local configuration). If the devices in your network react to broadcast messages or not depends on their configuratation. However sending a discovery message to the brodcast-address as you do, does not make much sense as it is not allowed to assign this IP address to any device.